# Java script function not called

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <body style="background-color: cornflowerblue" >
        <form action="Login" method="post" name="frmLogin">
            <table style="background-color: darkgrey" align="center" border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2" style="font-size: xx-large;color:darkmagenta" >Login Details</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold" >Username</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="txtUsername" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold">Password</td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="txtPassword" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2" >
                            <input type="button" onclick="return reset();" value="Reset" name="btnReset" />
                            <input type="submit" onclick="return submit();" value="Submit" name="btnSubmit" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        <script type="text/javascript"  language="javascript">
            function submit()
            {

                var username=frmlogin.document.txtUsername.vlaue;
                var password=frmlogin.document.txtPassword.vlaue;
                if(username=="")
                {
                    alert("Username Must be filled");
                    return false;
                }
                if(password=="")
                {
                    alert("Password Must be filled");
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            function reset()
            {
                frmlogin.document.txtUsername.vlaue="";
                frmlogin.document.txtPassword.vlaue="";
                return false;
            }
        </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have html code above, and on successfully submit I call a servlet name Login.

But it directly call the servlet. It skips the java script function.

And if i remove the form then  java script executes.

Comment: I am confused as to what the error/symptoms are...

Comment: I want to call servlet, but before it, want to validate in the java script. so how i can do this

Comment: see my answer, it is kinda the **standard** way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you gave the custom form validator function the **same** name as the form's default submit function `form.submit()`. The form's default submit function will have precedence in this context.

To fix this, you need to rename `submit()` to something else. E.g.

```
onclick="return validate();"
```

with

```
function validate() {
    // ...
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you've several major bugs in your JS function, the following line for example is completely wrong:

```
var username=frmlogin.document.txtUsername.vlaue;
```

but that's subject for a different question if you can't figure it out.

Last but not least, I hope that you're aware that JS can be disabled/spoofed by the client? Ensure that you're also validating the form in the server side. See also [our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) for a concrete example.

Comment: Read the error message and/or ask a new question and/or just re-read the whole line a few times yourself. This is offtopic to the current question.

Comment: but it gives not any error, and also not functionally correct

Comment: Back to your initial question, please. Did renaming the function name solve the initial problem of the function not being called or not?

Comment: yes renaming the function name is the solution, now it executes correctly. and the wrong line is now i write as document.frmLogin.txtusername.value

Comment: Now when i print the value of username and password it gives me undefined. can you hint me how i can do this to correct fetch the values

Comment: oops very sorry, it just by a mistake. I want to accept your answer, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

add the **onsubmit** event handler for the **form**:

```
<form action="Login" method="post" name="frmLogin" onsubmit="return submit();">
```

Comment: i want to call the java script method right form the Button click event

Comment: it just doesnt work that way, you can change **type=submit** to **type=button**, your javascript method will be called, but your jsp will not be called. boil down to one sentence： **it is just by design.**

Answer (score 1):

devang you need to capture event for the submit button click if you want to execute that javascript code. i am having the same problem but i solved it using jquery click events, because the by default it submits directly without moving through the code . if any alternate solution is there , please letme know too

btw jquery code can be written as

$("input[name=btnSubmit]").click(function(e) {

```
 ..if fails conditions..
 e.preventDefault();
```

});